# foobar2000: sorting tracks by date

Tags: foobar2000

How do you sort files by date in an autoplaylist when the date format is something like

```
2015-09-10 12:37:52
```

Do you have to convert this date format into another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%date%` to sort autoplaylists by date. Foobar understands the `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format.

[image]

To do so, right-click on your autoplaylist **tab** and select the menü entry `Autoplaylist ...`.
An example could look like this:

[image]

You can combine sort-patterns i.e.`%directory% - %date%`. Or extract and sort by specific time information by using one of these functions:

- > $year(time): Retrieves the year part (formatted as four digits) from a time/date string.
- > $month(time): Retrieves the month part (formatted as two digits) from a time/date string.
- > $day_of_month(time): Retrieves the day of month part (formatted as two digits) from a time/date string.
- > $date(time): Retrieves the date part (formatted as YYYY-MM-DD) from a time/date string.
- > $time(time): Retrieves the time part (formatted as HH:MM:SS or HH:MM) from a date/time string.

#### References

- [Foobar2000: Title Formatting Reference » Time/Date Functions](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Title_Formatting_Reference#Time.2FDate_Functions)